# Android Dialog headers, title, icon have disappeared

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

All of a sudden all of my Dialog Headers have disappeared. I have tried several phones (4.4.4 and 4.2.2) to test on and it still seems to be happening.

I am not to sure what could be causing this? I was doing some updates to my app (not on anything dialog related) and I noticed that all the dialogs had changed. All I can think is that when I did a gradle sync or something and it changed my apps theme. I use the Dialog Fragment is several different places and they all have changed.

Here is an example of my one Dialog Fragment.

[image: screencapture]

I have even tried specifying the style like so:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), STYLE_NORMAL);
```

What can I do to get my Title and Icons back?

Some code:

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), STYLE_NORMAL);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.password_icon);
    builder.setTitle(dialogTitle);
    builder.setMessage(dialogMessage);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            onDialogOkClick(dialog);
        }
    });
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.enterudlcode_dialog, null));
    return builder.create();
```

here is the XML of the screen shot above:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/enterudlcode_dialog_editText_panelcode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="numberPassword">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/enterudlcode_dialog_checkbox_remember_me"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="Remember Panel Code" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my apps theme / style file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.

        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="LoginFormContainer">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
    </style> 
 </resources>
```

Comment: remove  `STYLE_NORMAL`

Comment: I added `STYLE_NORMAL` hoping it would fix it. It didn't have it before. Will try again

Comment: Show your dialog XML

Comment: @Ajeet I have added it. Not sure how its xml will effect the dialog?

Comment: @Zapnologica remove setMessage and try again. Tell me if it doesn't help :)

Comment: @Ajeet Still the same sadly. I have also removed `STYLE_NORMAL` and made no difference.

Comment: did you recently made any changes to theme?

Comment: Nothing, That's what I find odd.  and I have no theme customization's relating to dialogs. I am in fact using the plain normal theme, android studio gives you when you make a project.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this problem in my code.

`builder.setTitle(dialogTitle);`

`dialogTitle` was null. I had changed a bundle name in another class and it was causing dialogTitle to be null in the class where I showed the dialog title.

I still don't know why the whole header disappeared and it didn't just put an empty title.

But I hope this can possibly help someone someday.